# Centering Text in Photoshop without shifting the text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I will sometimes encounter a font centered within an element, however upon checking the alignment, I will see that it is aligned left. Clicking the "center text" button in photoshop shifts the text layer left. Is there anyway to assign the "center text" property without having the text layer shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use a text box (drag out and define the area where I want my text to show up)

This way I can change the text alignment without shifting my text object

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a marquee on the canvas of the area you wish the text to be centered. Once you marquee the area `Press V` and at the top of the screen you can select center from the alignment options. By doing this, it does not matter if your text is left aligned or any alignment. It centers based on the layer. This method can also be used to centering height and works with any layer, not just type.

[image]